How does Potent Cantrip interact with spells that involve weapon attacks?
Potent Cantrip, a feature granted to the Evoker Wizard Subclass, states:

Your damaging cantrips affect even creatures that avoid the brunt of
the effect. When you cast a cantrip at a creature and you miss with
the attack roll or the target succeeds on a saving throw against the
cantrip, the target takes half the cantrip's damage (if any) but
suffers no additional effect from the cantrip.

How does this feature interact with spells that involve weapon attacks, such as Booming Blade, Green-Flame Blade, True Strike, Shillelagh, and similar spells?
Does the damage from the weapon interact with Potent Cantrip, or does it only apply to the spell's damage rolls?
A couple of notes:

Some spells behave differently depending on the character level
I think this sentence is also relevant to the interaction:


... the target takes half the cantrip's damage (if any) but suffers no
additional effect from the cantrip.


Do you think my answer, answers your question sufficiently, as that it might be accepted?

@TreeSpawned I was waiting for a different point of view—similar but more refined than nonymous' answer—because I have a different opinion about spells with a range of Self (XYZ). My understanding of the rules is more in line with this answer, the explanations given in this Reddit thread Spells w/ Range of Self, Rules Clarification or the explanations given by JC in the Dragon Talk Sage Advice: Targeting Revisited podcast (cont)

@TreeSpawned (cont) I mean, your answer is right if and only if your interpretation of 'Self (XYZ)' is as you said, but unfortunately, there are different opinions around the internet. One suggestion could be to also add this other point of view for future readers unless you consider it wrong and prefer to leave it as it is now.

You can always answer your own question if you think the correct answer is missing and you think you know what it should be. I would prefer to leave my own answer as is, but if another answer were to become highy upvoted, I would love to learn from it.

I find it difficult to decide what is raw on this kind of question since the word target has been hotly disputed for a decade now. However I would certainly rule that it works, and balance may be a better consideration than raw.

Related: Does Potent Spellcasting (Druid) work with Shillelagh?

RAW it only works if the Cantrip is cast at the opponent
The wording of the Subclass feature explicitly states, it can only be used (emphasis mine):

When you cast a cantrip at a creature

It the case of a spell like Fire Bolt or Ray of Frost, you are indeed casting that cantrip directly at the opponent. But in the case of the 4 spells you mentioned, that you are unsure of, you are not casting at the creature that receives the damage, you are casting the spell either on yourself, or on a weapon you carry. This is made clear by the Spell's range attribute. If it is a range of self, it does not count for this feature.
For example True Strike states:

Guided by a flash of magical insight, you make one attack [...]

Meaning the magical effect of this Cantrip is not the damage dealt to the opponent, it is you yourself improving your attack.
This is further supported by the fact that all but one of those spells you mentioned aren't of the Evocation School (only Green-Flame Blade is), while the ones that work with this Spell RAW mostly are, which makes sense for a Subclass feature of the Evoker Wizard, though there are exceptions, like Thorn Whip and Poison Spray.

I'm kind of late here, but I'll throw my answer out there. The only part that really matters is 'At a creature'. There's no definition for this anywhere in the rules, so we'll have to abide by the Good Faith reading of Potent Cantrip itself to decide what meaning that phrase has, and how it applies to the old weapon cantrips.
We can divide Potent Cantrip into parts, and deal with each one seprately.

'When you cast a cantrip' -- Fairly self-explanatory, and all of the cantrip listed above are, indeed, cantrips.
'At a creature' -- The point at issue, and we'll have to read the rest of the rule in good faith to define this properly.
'And you miss with the attack roll or the target succeeds on a saving throw against the cantrip' -- All of the cantrips listed above (except Shilleleagh, which is obviously excluded) make an attack roll, so, at first glance, they all meet the qualifications. Furthermore, is making an attack roll against a creature or forcing a creature to make a saving throw covered in any rule? Yes, and that rule is the 'Target' rule. It reads as follows: "A target is the creature or object targeted by an attack roll, forced to make a saving throw by an effect, or selected to receive the effects of a spell or another phenomenon." Thus, using the good faith rule, we can conclude that the 'At a creature' segment of the Potent Cantrip ability is a modification of the 'Target' rule that requires us to target a creature instead of either a creature or an object.

Another part of the initial question is what do we do about cantrips that have a range of 'Self'? First, what is Range?
From the spellcasting rules: A spell’s range indicates how far from the spellcaster the spell’s effect can originate, and the spell’s description specifies which part of the effect is limited by the range.
A range usually takes one of the following forms:
Distance. The range is expressed in feet.
Touch. The spell’s effect originates on something the spellcaster must touch, as defined in the spell.
Self. The spell is cast on the spellcaster or emanates from them, as specified in the spell.
If a spell has movable effects, they aren’t restricted by its range unless the spell’s description says otherwise.
We then have to ask whether a spell with a Range of Self is targetting the caster. The Target rule allows a target to be a creature selected to recieve the effects of a spell. Does the caster of a spell with a Range of Self apply the effects of the spell to themselves as a target? That depends on the effect applied, according to the Effects rule of the Spellcasting rules, which reads (in part) as follows:
The effects of a spell are detailed after its duration entry. Those details present exactly what the spell does, which ignores mundane physical laws; any outcomes beyond those effects are under the DM’s purview. Whatever the effects, they typically deal with targets, saving throws, attack rolls, or all three, each of which is detailed below.
Targets
A typical spell requires the caster to pick one or more targets to be affected by the spell’s magic. A spell’s description says whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or something else.
A Clear Path to the Target. To target something with a spell, a caster must have a clear path to it, so it can’t be behind Total Cover.
Targeting Yourself. If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself unless the creature must be Hostile or specifically a creature other than you.
Areas of Effect. Some spells, such as Thunderwave, cover an area called an area of effect, which is defined in the rules glossary. The area determines what the spell targets. The description of a spell specifies whether it has an area of effect, which is typically one of these shapes: Cone, Cube, Cylinder, Emanation, Line, or Sphere.
Thus, by a good faith reading of the rules, Range tells you only the possible distance at which a spell effect can be applied, and does not tell you what can be the target or targets of the spell's effect, and the Effect rule specifies that the spell description defines the possible target or targets of the spells effect. Thus, in good faith, Range does not determine the target of the spell, the spell effect determines the target of the spell. Thus, Booming Blade, Greenflame Blade, and True Strike, all of which have a Range of Self, have an effect which specifies what the spell can target. Both Booming Blade and Green-Flame Blade have a Range of Self (5 feet), which the spell description qualifies as the range at which you can make a melee attack with the weapon used in the spell's casting.
At this point, I think we've established the following: Any cantrip, regardless of the specified Range, that allows you to select a target or targets as a part of the effect, and permits an attack roll against that target or targets, or forces the target or targets to make a saving throw, meets the qualifications of the first three parts of the Potent Cantrip ability, so long as you miss the attack roll or rolls, or the target or targets succeed on their saving throw.

'The target takes half the cantrip's damage (if any) but suffers no additional effect from the cantrip' -- this last point is fairly simple: if you would deal damage as a result of hitting with an attack roll or as a result of a target failing a saving throw, you may deal half of this damage if you miss an attack roll or the target succeeds on their saving throw.


Potent Cantrip interacts with some such spells
TreeSpawned's answer covers many key points but misses some nuances.
Technically, for Potent Cantrip, a cantrip only needs to be cast "at a creature," and this creature doesn't have to be someone else—therefore, spells that explicitly target another creature and spells "cast at" the caster qualify. So long as the caster targets a creature and misses with an attack roll or the target succeeds on a saving throw, Potent Cantrip applies.
Spells like Green-Flame Blade and Booming Blade have a range of self (5 ft) and involve attack rolls. The spell descriptions clearly state that the creature you attack is the "target," as seen in:

"On a hit, the target suffers..."

Since a spell’s description defines its target, these spells even meet the condition of being cast at another creature for Potent Cantrip purposes1.
While the

weapon attack's normal effects

are an explicit part of the spell's effects, it would be reasonable to exempt the weapon attack's damage from Potent Cantrip, since the weapon attack is arguably distinct from the spell's magical damage. However, technically, the attack damage is subject to Potent Cantrip, as well.
True Strike indisputably is cast "at a creature"--the caster (whom is "guided by a flash of magical insight")--and it involves an attack roll; though, it doesn't refer to the other creature as a target. So, it technically qualifies, RAW, though maybe not RAI.
Shillelagh, however, doesn’t qualify, as it lacks an attack roll in the cantrip’s effect.
1: Of note, this is the reason that these spells could not be cast on a Paladin's Found Steed in the 2014 rules.

Booming and Green-Flame Blade are cast at a weapon - not a creature. After the spell has been cast, you can later make an attack with the weapon and the target of the attack gets the additional effect from the on-going spell on the weapon.

Technically, the weapon is just the material component in the casting.  These spells are not cast on a weapon, since they have a range of self(AoE) and target another creature.

@nonymous, as I mentioned in my question's comments, I share the same point of view as you regarding spells with a range of 'Range: Self (X radius, line, etc.).' However, for your answer to be accepted, I think it needs to reference some official rules or rulings.

"The target" could just as well mean the target of the weapon attack you make, rather than the target of the cantrip. In any case, Potent Cantrip would only affect the damage from the cantrip, suck as the thunder damage from Booming Blade, not the damage from the weapon attack.

@JoakimM.H. The weapon attack is not distinct from the cantrip. Rather, it one of the spell's effects (https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dnd/phb-2024/spells#Effects). So the target of the attack is eo ipso the target of the cantrip. Likewise, the attack damage is a part of the cantrip.

@nonymous I disagree. I can agree that "you make a melee attack" is an effect of the spell. But the attack itself is not. You cannot, for instance, use Agonizing Blast with booming blade to add your charisma modifier to the melee attack's damage.

@JoakimM.H., the "attack's normal effects" are an explicit part of the spell's effects. RAW, you can add Agonizing Blast to Booming Blade under the Expanded Rules. Unless you've found something specific that says otherwise?

If the cantrip's listed target is "self", then you are the target of the spell. So if you miss, you would effectively damage yourself.

@JoelHarmon Its range, not its target, is self. Also, no.

Ah, my mistake on the range thing. So you are suggesting that the target of these cantrips can (or even must) be out of the range of these cantrips.  My previous quip about self-damage was intended to provide an amusing consequence of this possible view point, and I am not sure why you think it wouldn't be the case (other than it being a bit absurd on its face).

My point is that the relationship between a spell's 1) range, 2) implicit targets, 3) explicit targets, and 4) effects do not overlap neatly with the wording of Potent Cantrips "...cast a cantrip at a creature...". And, spells with range of "Self" sometimes qualify.

True Strike is an odd case because it affects the caster, but makes an attack roll against another creature. Does it target the caster? Technically, no; it doesn't have any targets. Nevertheless it is cast "at a creature", which is all Potent Cantrip requires. Narratively, there is nothing wrong with "empowering" True Strike like this. E.g. "You missed, but your potent cantrip guided you better than a non-potent one would have. You still deal half damage."

Thanks for improving the answer! The only difference between my understanding and yours is that I believe Potent Cantrip doesn't improve the mundane weapons used in BB, GFB, or True Strike. It only interacts with the "damaging cantrips" part of the spell. So in my opinion, BB and GFB don't interact with Potent Cantrip before 5th level, and it will affect True Strike if you choose radiant damage. In other words: Potent Cantrip interacts with the sonic/fire/radiant damage of those cantrips. Please let me know if you think this other perspective could be added as another option in your answer.

@Tarod, how's that?

@nonymous I see the answer now includes the case about not considering the weapon's damage for Potent Cantrip. Fair enough.
